storing big data(1000 lines per second) and reading in realtime in c#
Please I want to create an application which manage data in C# in windows in realTime. In fact I want to prepare a concept for an application which receive data each millisecond from another application . So we will receive approximately 1000 lines per second. we will save only 600000 lines ( as first implementation, we can have more than this value. May be it will be 1000000 lines )and when we receive a new data, we will delete the oldest one. As a first idea we can save 1000 lines in a buffer and after that we delete the oldest 1000 lines in database and save the new one but I don t know there is any other solution better than this one.
As a first idea we can save 1000 lines in a buffer and after that we delete the oldest 1000 lines in database and save the new one but I don t know there is any other solution better than this one.

For real time requirements that actually are, neither windows nor .Net/C# are the tools of choice.

Nonsense, C# and .NET handle real-time applications at scale just fine.

You could have one slot (one record) for every second in a given period of time. E.g. 900 slots storing data for 15 minutes. Then the current second modulo 900 will be your slot number. Then you can
UPDATE myTable SET Data = newData WHERE SlotNr = nr

Where the the slot number is the total number of seconds modulo the number of slots. This will automatically overwrite the oldest data.
You will have to create empty slots to initialize the table. But then you can insert the new lines and delete the oldest ones in a single UPDATE command.

if the application crashed after 3 or 4  minutes I will lose the new data. I want to have always the newest one

You will have always the newest one with this approach, because you update the data every second. In my example you have the latest 900 seconds (=15 Minutes) of data stored in 900 records. But how are you expecting it to work if the application crashes? How do you expect it to work without a running application?

I would start by thinking a bit more about the specific requirements:

What operations do you need to support? What values will you be reading? Do you need to compute some kind of statistics over all lines in the buffer?
What are the bandwith requirements? How large are your lines? Are each line the same size?
What are the latency requirements?
What are the CPU requirements?
What kind of error handling is needed? What are the consequences crashes or other problems?
Is persistence needed? If you need to reboot the server and it takes 10 minutes, are the previous 600k lines still relevant?
How will the applications communicate? Are they on the same machine? Same data center? How reliable is the network?
Are you required to use any specific kind of protocol for communication?
What kind of hardware can you expect? An embedded computer? A large server?
If you upgrade the application, will you need to migrate existing data?

These answers should guide the development. I would not presume that a database is necessarily the best solution. Perhaps a in memory ringbuffer is sufficient? Or a memory mapped file? Also note that there is often a tradeoff between latency and bandwith, bandwith is often improved by batching larger chunks of data, at the expense of latency.

What operations do you need to support? What values will you be reading? Do you need to compute some kind of statistics over all lines in the buffer? The main task is to read asynchronous values from robot. As example of values 2024-05-07 08:02:28.322;True;True;False;8;45.499878;7;START;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0. We have one line per millisecond. No need to compute any thing. Just we need to save 10 or 20 minutes and so to save new data and delete the old one
The application will run until the robot from which we receive data crashes or it stopped by the user .

@MounaATTIA This sounds like a simple circular buffer should be sufficient. This could be implemented either in memory only, or continuously saved to disk, depending on your requirements.
